# How to change the values of settings that belong to referenced project after compile time

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a solution with 3 projects (A,B,C). In A and B I created a file of settings. In C I have referenced to A and B. After compile time if I change the value of setting in A.exe.config and B.exe.config in theirs bin folders and run the A.exe e B.exe the changing that I make have affect. But if I change A.exe.config and B.exe.config in the C's bin folder and run C.exe the changing that I make haven't affect. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C.exe will only look for configuration file C.exe.config, you may need to define all the configurations for A and B as well within this file. Unless you are just learning, I am quite certain this is not a good design.

Comment: Is there a way to import the settings?